# Реализация цикл в Masm`e

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

Нужно было вывести строку заданное количество раз. Очевидно, что нужно это делать с помощью цикла, однако вопрос вот в чем: зачем помещать и доставать потом `ecx` из стека? Почему не получается без этого?

Вот этот участок кода:

```
LoopPrint:
push ecx
invoke WriteConsoleA, hStdout, offset text, sizeof text, 0, 0
pop ecx
dec ecx
jnz LoopPrint
```

Comment: Ну наверное, `WriteConsoleA` пишет в этот регистр, не сохраняя его. Посмотрите соглашение о вызовах, которое использует эта функция, и используйте другой регистр

Answer (score 1):

MSDN, статья [x64 Software Conventions / Register Usage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z1stfyw.aspx). Если в таблице не указано явно что регистр "должен сохраняться вызываемым объектом", то полагаться на его значение, которое было до вызова вызова функции, нельзя.

```
Регистр     статус      Применение 
RAX         Временный   Регистр возвращаемого значения
RCX         Временный   Первый целочисленный аргумент
RDX         Временный   Второй целочисленный аргумент
...
RDI         Постоянный  Должен сохраняться вызываемым объектом
RSI         Постоянный  Должен сохраняться вызываемым объектом
RBX         Постоянный  Должен сохраняться вызываемым объектом
RBP         Постоянный  Может использоваться как указатель кадра.
                        Должен сохраняться вызываемым объектом
RSP         Постоянный  Указатель стека
...
```

Для 32- и 16-битных архитектур есть небольшие отличия, но в любом случае сохранность регистра `ecx` (`cx`) во время работы функции не гарантируется.

Comment: Можно, к примеру, rbx/[ebx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561502(v=vs.85).aspx) регистр для цикла использовать вместо ecx (вызываемая функция должна сохранить rbx значение), если loop инструкция не используется. То есть слово "volatile" в данном случае означает, что значение регистра не сохраняется вызываемой функцией и поэтому самостоятельно такие регистры предохранять необходимо.

Comment: @jfs, навскидку не вспомню, но вроде бы в 32/16 требований к сохранению ebx/bx не было. А в 64-битном варианте это уже ABI.

Comment: я специально ссылку привёл, чтобы на память не рассчитывать.  Там написано какие регистры функция может изменить (функции обязаны сохранить ebx согласно документации).

Comment: @jfs, по вашей ссылке ничего про сохранение ebx не вижу. Sorry, вижу: *"Functions must preserve all registers, except for eax, ecx, and edx"*